# Iterative Methods without Local Contraction

Tags: numerical-methods

It seems to me that many iterative methods in numerical analysis leverage some sort of local contraction to show that a solution will converge to a fixed point. Is this true of all iterative methods or are there iterative methods which do not require local contraction?

Comment: Depends on how strictly you define your terms - basically, if $a^*$ is the solution to your problem, and $a$ is some guess of the solution, then each step of the iterative method ought to bring you closer to $a^*$. "Getting closer" is (again, depending on your definition) arguably equivalent to "the method is contractive around $a^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something interesting in this direction may be the fact that Nesterov's accelerated gradient descent is known for occasionally increasing your function error. [Here](http://blog.mrtz.org/2014/08/18/robustness-versus-acceleration.html) is an example with some pictures of that and discussion.